# Change text color of alert dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have a popup for downloading the audio instruction in my app. What I am trying to do is to change the default text color of "OK" to blue. I tried something but it's not working. Here is my code:

```
 private void showDownloadPgmPopup() {

    android.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("Download instructional audio?");
    builder.setMessage(ParamConstants.AUDIODOWNLOADPERMISSION);
    builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            WwDatabaseHelper.storeSelectedWeekAndDay(getActivity(), mSelectedWeekDataModel);
            goToMoveScreen();
        }
    });
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            AndroidDownloadFileByProgressBarActivity.StartAudioAssetDownload(getActivity());

        }

    }).create();
    // change the text color of download instruction ok button


    final android.app.AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();
    dialog.setOnShowListener( new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
                                  @Override
                                  public void onShow(DialogInterface arg0) {
                                      dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff5722"));
                                  }
                              });
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    dialog.show();
}
```

But the change is not taking effect, can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a Custom Dialog box in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341560/how-to-create-a-custom-dialog-box-in-android)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You have to provide a custom style id in the AlertDialog constructor:

```
AlertDialog.Builder(Context context, int themeResId)
```

and the style file should be something like:

```
<style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:colorAccent">#0000FF</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Another suggestion would be theme with **`<item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/MyStyle</item>`** where `MyStyle` should be something like **`<style name="MyStyle" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert"> </style>`** (warning `android:alertDialogTheme` will auto-complete but does not work!)

Answer (score 35):

Change your method to

```
private void showDownloadPgmPopup() {

    android.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.app
               .AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(),R.style.AlertDialog);
...
..
.   
}
```

And under res/values/styles.xml add a new AlertDialog style

```
<style name="AlertDialog" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#595959</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">#1b5e20</item>
    </style>
```

Below is the screen shot of these changes

[image: See dialog box color changes]

Answer (score 15):

Try calling the `setTextColor` after `show`. Refer below:

```
show()
dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setTextColor(Color.YELLOW)
```

Comment: Great!!! Thanks. Worked for me. As I was using  material design theme none of the other answers worked.

Answer (score 7):

**You have two ways to do this**

> 1. Override default dialog.

```
//1. create a dialog object 'dialog'
MyCustomDialog builder = new MyCustomDialog(getActivity(), "Exit", errorMessage); 
AlertDialog dialog = builder.setNegativeButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    ...
                }

            }).create();
//2. now setup to change color of the button
dialog.setOnShowListener( new OnShowListener() {
    @Override
    public void onShow(DialogInterface arg0) {
        dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#f34235"));
    }
}

dialog.show()
```

> 2. Create your own `custom` dialog

```
// create instance of dialog
AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

// get inflater and inflate layour for dialogue 
LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_label_editor, null);

// now set layout to dialog
dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

// create instance like this OR directly mentioned in layout
Button button= (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.label_field);
button.setText("test label");
AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();

// show dialog
alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 4):

I could manage to change the text color to Red by using *SpannableString* in place of normal string.

Example -

```
var okString = new SpannableString("OK");
okString.SetSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.Red), 0, Strings.Report.Length, 0);
```

I then passed the variable *okString* to setItems().

Try passing spannableString to setPositiveButton().

Answer (score 2):

Simply, you just change your "OK" text with this code:

`Html.fromHtml("<font color='#0000FF'>OK</font>")`

This code will totally change your text color depend on your added color value while #0000FF is blue.

Comment: The color was just ignored in my case. Not sure why.

Comment: I had the same problem, so I had to use the `setSpan` method from `SpannableString`.

Answer (score 1):

```
dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setTextColor(Color.YELLOW)
```

The above code didn't work for me, but the below one did work:

```
dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Yellow));
```

Answer (score 1):

With the Material Components library just define a custom style using the `buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle` attribute:

```
  <!-- Alert Dialog -->
  <style name="MaterialAlertDialog_OK_color" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">
    <!-- Style for positive button -->
    <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/PositiveButtonStyle.textColor</item>
  </style>

  <style name="PositiveButtonStyle.textColor" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/......</item>
  </style>
```

Then:

```
 new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context,
        R.style.MaterialAlertDialog_OK_color)
        .setMessage("Message......")
        .setPositiveButton("ok", null)
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
        .show();
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can use `MaterialAlertDialogBuilder` to show and customise your AlertDialog.

If you want more details, should definitely check out here.
https://www.journaldev.com/309/android-alert-dialog-using-kotlin

```kotlin
val builder = MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(requireContext())
with(builder) {
    setTitle(R.string.log_out)
    setMessage(R.string.dialog_msg_logout)
    setPositiveButton(R.string.confirm) { _, _ ->
        logoutUser()
    }
    setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, null)
}

val dialog = builder.create()
dialog.show()

val button = dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE)
with(button) {
    setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.colorAccent))
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For those looking to change the body text color, as I was, and kept finding this page, the solution is here:
https://lcdsmao.medium.com/material-design-custom-alert-dialog-5a9cab3ade11