# How to change the color of an AlertDialog message?

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I have an `AlertDialog` and it's message is displayed, but the color of the text is white. It blends in with the background. I've tried changing the theme but it doesn't work. How do I change the color of the message?

The relevant code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder;
builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivityGame.this);

builder.setTitle("Name");
builder.setMessage("Are you ");
builder.setCancelable(false);
builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        //Submit default name, go home
        boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData(defaultName, triesTaken, difficultyText);
        if (isInserted) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivityGame.this, "Your name was submitted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivityGame.this, "Error, your name wasn't submitted\n Have you entered a default name?\n Go to Settings/Default Name to set it up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivityGame.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        userName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        submitName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        submitName.setEnabled(true);
        dialogInterface.dismiss();
    }
});
builder.create();
builder.show();
```

Comment: Did you try to research for an answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16200914/alertdialog-styling-how-to-change-style-color-of-title-message-etc https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38609262/change-text-color-of-alert-dialog

Answer (score 63, accepted):

you can give style to your alert dialog like this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.AlertDialogStyle);
```

and the style is like always:

```
<style name="AlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:colorAccent">#f3f3f3</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#f3f3f3</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#f3f3f3</item>
</style>
```

Comment: You can apply the above style to all alert dialogs in themes.xml as follows
 
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogStyle</item>

Answer (score 1):

You can either use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16200914/alertdialog-styling-how-to-change-style-color-of-title-message-etc#answer-24560017) method, like @KarimElGhandour mentioned or just create your custom `Layout` in the `res\layout` folder and then apply it with `alertDialog.setView(LayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.yourlayout), yourRootView`.

Comment: Thank you, I created my own theme and added it to the initialization of the AlertDialog.

Answer (score 0):

In the Style even you can change **gravity** and **Mode**:

```
<style name="WelcomeStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="android:background">#FFD600</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#C51162</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#00B8D4</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:justificationMode">inter_word</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.DialogStyle);
```

styles.xml

```
  <style name="AlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:colorAccent">#303030</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#494949</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">#201D1D</item>
</style>
```