# Android Alert Dialog - How to change the title color and the text color without changing the primary color

Tags: android, dialog, alert, android-alertdialog, android-styles

Hay,

Is there a **simple** way to change the `title` and the `text` colour without changing the primary colour of the whole app?

Here is what I got now:

[image]

I dont want to change the `textColorPrimary`

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38609262/change-text-color-of-alert-dialog

Answer (score 7):

First, create a style definition like this:

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">your color here</item>
</style>
```

Then, when you create the dialog, instead of using the `AlertDialog.Builder(Context)` constructor, use the `AlertDialog.Builder(Context, int)` method and pass a reference to your style:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.DialogTheme)
        .setTitle("Hello world")
        .setMessage("some longer text for the body of the dialog")
        .show();
```

[image]

Even though this depends on changing `textColorPrimary`, it doesn't do so in a way that affects anything else in your app.

Comment: that didnt change anything.. Plus I had to do other things to hide the box shadow effect such as `bottomBright`, `topDark` and `topBright`

Comment: @RaheelHasan are you importing `android.app.AlertDialog` or the support library version `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog`?

Comment: yep, this didn't work for me as well!

Answer (score 1):

Simple and easy to implement:

```
SpannableString title = new SpannableString("Your title");
                title.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color)), 0, title.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

then just pass as title in

```
new AlertDialogBuilder(context).setTitle(title).show();
```

Do the same with the message.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, you just change your "TITLE" text with this code:

`Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FFFFFF'>TITLE</font>")`

This code will totally change your text color depend on your added color value. You can also use it for button's text as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#0288D1'>This is a test</font>"));
builder.setPositiveButton(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#0288D1'>Yes</font>"), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Yes");
    }
});
builder.setNegativeButton(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#0288D1'>No</font>"), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "No");
    }
});
builder.create();
builder.show();
```