# MaterialComponents AlertDialog text color

Tags: android, material-design, android-alertdialog, material-components-android, material-components

Reading [MaterialComponents theme alert dialog buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52829954/materialcomponents-theme-alert-dialog-buttons) and https://medium.com/@lcdsmao/material-design-custom-alert-dialog-5a9cab3ade11 I set `AlertDialog` buttons and text colors of new Material Theme.

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <!-- AlertDialog -->
    <item name="materialAlertDialogBodyTextStyle">@style/MaterialAlertDialogTextTheme</item>
    <item name="materialAlertDialogTheme">@style/MaterialAlertDialogButtonsTheme</item>
</style>

<!-- AlertDialog text -->
<style name="MaterialAlertDialogTextTheme" parent="MaterialAlertDialog.MaterialComponents.Body.Text">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimaryitem>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>

<!-- AlertDialog buttons -->
<style name="MaterialAlertDialogButtonsTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">
    <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/AlertDialog.Button</item>
    ...
```

After creating an `AlertDialogFragment` using

```
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState)

    return MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context!!).apply {
        ...
    }.create()
}
```

I get

[image]

As you see, buttons colors have changed, but *text color and style haven't changed*.

Then I tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/51936236/2914140:

```
<style name="AlertDialog" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#005B82</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#1b5e20</item>
</style>

...
    return MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context!!, R.style.AlertDialog).apply {
```

and got

[image]

How to do the same without adding `AlertDialog` theme, only redefining Material theme?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With the Material Components you can use a style like:

```
<!-- Alert Dialog -->
  <style name="MyThemeOverlay.MaterialAlertDialog" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">

      <!-- Title -->
      <item name="materialAlertDialogTitleTextStyle">@style/MyTitle_MaterialAlertDialog.MaterialComponents.Title.Text</item>


     <!-- Body -->
     <item name="materialAlertDialogBodyTextStyle">@style/BodyTextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body2</item>

     <!-- Buttons -->
     <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/PositiveButtonStyle</item>
     <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/NegativeButtonStyle</item>
     <item name="buttonBarNeutralButtonStyle">....</item>
  </style>


  <style name="PositiveButtonStyle" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="backgroundTint">#00f</item>
  </style>

  <style name="NegativeButtonStyle" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/primaryDarkColor</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyTitle_MaterialAlertDialog.MaterialComponents.Title.Text" parent="@style/MaterialAlertDialog.MaterialComponents.Title.Text">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/MyTitle_TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle1</item>
  </style>

  <style name="BodyTextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body2" parent="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body2">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">sans-serif-condensed-light</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

Then you can refer this style in the constructor like:

```
    new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context,
        R.style.MyThemeOverlay.MaterialAlertDialog)
```

or you can set it as default in your app theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">

     <item name="materialAlertDialogTheme">@style/MyThemeOverlay.MaterialAlertDialog
    </item>

</style>
```

Comment: Thanks! Also I changed `parent="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body2"` to `parent="@style/MaterialAlertDialog.MaterialComponents.Body.Text"` (though it doesn't matter). My mistake was putting `materialAlertDialogBodyTextStyle` into `AppTheme`, not `MyThemeOverlay.MaterialAlertDialog`.